# CSS Div respect othe divs

Tags: css, html

I would like to make the divs responsive. I have three divs:

```
LEFT | MIDDLE | RIGHT
```

Since this is for a mobile website, I have to be able to respect screen sizes. So I would like to the `Middle` div (which contains a `input`) resize and not the others.

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxmL/62/

If you grab the jsfiddle separator and push to the right, the image on the right will drop to another line. 
I would like to maintain both of images in their sides and resize the middle div.

Plus, I would like the `middle div` to be full width, which means it will only have a space between the `image left` and `image right` of (lets say `20px`).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the solution:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div.header .middle{
       width: 40%;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/sbxmL/63/
with `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {` you can set css that makes the size of your middle smaller when she screen is smaller than 600px

Answer (score 1):

Try this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kKJnb

As you asked only the `.middle` div change its width, while `.left` and `.right` have a fixed width. I've used `calc()` function so this example will work on all modern browser (anyway not on `IE < 9` or `Safari < 6`). The div are floated so you may need to apply a clearing to the parent element.

Relevant CSS

```
.header * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header div { 
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #c0d6c3;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 50px; // fixed width
}

.middle {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

/* 96% so you have a small space between images */
input { width: 96%; }
```